# how to break blocks in MInecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing minecraft and noticed that I couldn't break blocks with tools or my fist. I check to make sure I'm in survival mode and that cheats were enabled.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just clicking? :)

Comment: Could you be more specific? You do have to hold down the mouse button to break blocks in survival mode. Not just press.

Comment: PC, Xbox, or Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1):

To break blocks, you need to hold down the right button on the mouse.

Comment: Left by default I believe, right mouse button places blocks.

Comment: Really? because when I play on my PC, the right mouse button usually break them, if you hold it. @DBS